Is there a breaker handle lockoff that fits eaton/bryant double pole GFCIs?
I want to replace my existing BR240 wall oven double pole breaker with a new Eaton double pole GFCI.
The existing lockoff for the BR240 is the standard Eaton BRLWCS lockoff for BR breakers and it does not work with either the new BRN240GF or the older GFTCB240 breaker.  The lockoff has tangs that snap into notches on the ends of the breaker face so that it holds onto the face of the breaker, and it provides slots for a small lock to hold the breaker handle open or closed.  In the case of the older generation (GFTCB) there are no notches to accept the tangs on the BRLWCS.  In the case of the new redesigned BRN240GF the tangs are present but there is a raised hump on the bottom of the breaker face that houses the test button.  That hump will not allow the lockoff to seat on the breaker face.
Have any of you dealt with this?  Any ideas for a lockoff for Eaton/bryant double pole GFCIs?
I'm surprised it hasn't come up since GFCIs are now required for most appliances.  Wall ovens in particular often require hard wiring, thus requiring something other an a cord+plug for a disconnect.
If I can't find a code-compliant lockoff (one that stays with the breaker when unlocked)  I'm going to have to install a line of sight disconnect somewhere in the cabinetry, which is made more difficult due to the ampacity of the required switch.  A circuit breaker as a disconnect would have to be readily accessible, and there is just no way to mount a small breaker panel nearby that would pass muster for accessibility.  There are beefy enough double pole snap switches available (leviton makes a 60a version) that will fit a 4 square box.  So, if I can't find a working lockoff, I'll  be able to mount a switch in a somewhat accessible location but it will either have some visual impact or will be buried in a less visible but also less accessible location. This is a lot of trouble for a less than ideal result; I would really prefer a lockoff in the main panel.

A quick search on the Eaton web site didn't turn up anything useful. But rather than a switch - big switches tend to get very expensive - you could use an air conditioner disconnect. Plenty of name-brand UL listed products (e.g., GE) for under $20.

Yeah, I'm aware, but those style discos would be ugly if in a visible accessible location in kitchen cabinetry.   At least a snap switch in a 4 square box could be somewhat hidden - I believe there is some leeway for accessibility (e.g., behind a drawer) since there would be no breaker to reset or fuse to replace, just a disco switch for when the oven is to be pulled for service.  Here's what I was looking at using: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003AU8QUS?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

Would a disconnect placed in the circuit next to the breaker panel work, if used with a lockout?

It would be easy  but I think NEC only allows it if the disco is a breaker in a sub, as the "out of sight from the appliance" disco exception is for when the disco is the OCPD for the circuit. So I could do a little 2 pole panel, with the GFI  feeding it in the main and the breaker in the 2 pole panel being a lockable BR240 acting as the disco.  A lot of trouble to get a lockout but easier in a basement than my nice kitchen cabinets.  Still hoping there's a lockoff out there :-)  If another brand 1" lockoff fits it could probably slide by the AHJ it's just metal in a dead front :-)

Looks like 422.31(B) is the out of sight exception I was thinking of.  DIYSE won't let me edit the above comment after 5 mins.

You're after a BHGW
GFTCB breakers use a BHGW lockoff according to Page V1-T1-86 of the Eaton catalog.

That's a single pole lockoff.

Thanks for the lead, I hadn't seen that one.  Unfortunately, there is no picture unless I'm missing it.  I'm afraid it may be a removable one similar to BRLW2 since the description says it attaches to the handle.  BRLW2 looks like it has to be removed to close the breaker.  As I understand it NEC requires that the device stay in place whether the lock is used or not.  I take that to mean no temporary solutions.  Also, I really hope there is one for the newer gen (e.g., BRN240GF)  as GFTCB does not work for some other appliances (my heat pump, for one) while the newer series does work OK.
